# How to prevent JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject error?

Tags: java, json

In my code, when I put JSONObjects inside a JSONArray, I can read it using getJSONObject call
However when I add JSONArray inside another JSONObject & then fetch the array & then try to call getJSONObject, I get an error `JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject.` How can I avoid this error ?

```
final JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();
jsonArray.put(new JSONObject().put("id", "id1"));
jsonArray.put(new JSONObject().put("id", "id2"));

for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  System.out.println("--------------- everything is smooth and fine --------------------: " + jsonArray.getJSONObject(i));
}

// stuffed array inside an object.
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.append("key", jsonArray);

// refetched the array.
final JSONArray responseArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("key");
for (int i = 0; i < responseArray.length(); i++) {
  // error - JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject.
  System.out.println("----------------- errors out ------------------: " + responseArray.getJSONObject(i));
}
```

Comment: What do you think `append` does? Why do you think so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `put` instead:

```
// stuffed array inside an object.
final JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("key", jsonArray);
```